# Php setcookie not working

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Tengo varios archivos:

- variables.php: en éste he definido las variables globales necesarias.
- compruebaLogin.php: aquí compruebo el usuario, contraseña, etc. y si el usuario quiere que recuerde su usuario y contraseña, creo una cookie con el usuario, tal que así:

```
        $query = "UPDATE usuario SET cookie='".$rand."' WHERE id_usuario=".$row["id_usuario"];
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                if ( false===$result ) {
                    die("Conexión errónea: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                    header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['localhost'] . 'Error');
                }
        setcookie("id_usuario", $row["id_usuario"], time()+(60*60*24*365), '/');
        setcookie("marca", $rand, time()+(60*60*24*365), '/');
```

- navbar.php (incluido dentro del archivo index.html): aquí, después de hacer en compruebaLogin.php un header('Location:'..,  puedo ver el valor de las cookies "id_usuario" y "marca". Pero sin embargo no puedo ver una nueva cookie "prueba" que hago al entrar en índex.html, algo así como:

```
 
setcookie("prueba", "prueba", time()+(60*60*24*365), '/');
$prueba = filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, "prueba");
```

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Valor cookie prueba: ". $prueba ."');</script>";
```

pero no imprime nada de la variable $prueba, he probado todo (ob_start(), ob_end_flush(), crearla en prueba.php, directamente con $_COOKIE['prueba']). 
¿Alguien sabe si la cookie se crea al hacer un redirect o header:location o se puede crear en la misma página que se va a visualizar en el momento? Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Queres que esa cookie se te muestre como alert? Esta en php haciendo un echo que se va a ejecutar como javascript por el alert creo que lo que te falta para que lo muestre es declarar que eso es un script echo "<script>alert('Valor cookie prueba: ". $prueba ."')</script>;"; por que ejecuto y me sale el alert con la cookie y se crea ok, o tal vez no estoy entendiendo correctamente tu planteo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Juan, sí que lo tengo puesto pero el formato al realizar la web me lo quitaba, ya está editado con el código bien.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si probas ha obtener usando $_COOKIE, el codigo sería así:

```
setcookie("prueba", "prueba", time()+(60*60*24*365), '/');
$prueba = $_COOKIE['prueba'];
echo "alert('Valor cookie prueba: ". $prueba ."');"
```

Comment: Gracias Germán por responder, pero tal como pongo en mi pregunta lo he probado y no funciona. He llegado a la conclusión que para que se cree la cookie debe haber una redirección en la web.. :-(

Comment: Raro que no te funcione el codigo que te puse, yo lo probe y a mi me funciona

Comment: Tal vez es algo en base a la forma en que se crea tu pagina, por si venis medio flojo con cookies te dejo esto a mi me ayudo en su momento, https://www.udemy.com/programador-web-php-cookies-y-sesiones/ es gratis y cubre bastante cookie solo tenes que tener cuenta creada, ahora dejo que alguien mas pueda ayudarte, a mi ya no se me ocurre mas nada jaja

Comment: Pues muchas gracias Juan, ya lo estoy viendo.

Answer (score 0):

El error que ahí veo es que estás intentando acceder al la variable en el mismo script donde lo has creado, antes de poder acceder a éste, primero deves crearlo, por ejemplo, archivo1.php > "Aquí crear la cookie", archivo2.php > "aquí puede consultarlo mediante un echo, var_dump o print".
sin embargo, también hay que tomar en cuenta que el dominio requerido para crear una cookie debe contener al menos dos puentos por lo que localhost no funcionará y el navegador se negará a crear la cookie... < en el manual viene el siguiente ejemplo que funcionará tanto en localhost como en un un dominio establecido.

$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie('cookiename', 'data', time()+60*60*24*365, '/', $domain, false);

Answer (score 0):

1.- setcookie se ejecuta en el lado del cliente
2.- $_COOKIE es un array que contiene las cookies exixtentes en el cliente al momento de iniciar el(los) script...

Por lo tanto;

```
setcookie("prueba", "prueba", time()+(60*60*24*365), '/'); //indica al navegador que cree la cookie, NO a php
$prueba = $_COOKIE['prueba']; // como el navegador no ha creado la cookie $prueba=null
echo "alert('Valor cookie prueba: ". $prueba ."');" // $prueba=nul, no funciona
```

en otras palabras si quieres ver lo que le mandaste al navegador, tienes dos opciones;

1.- Con codigo del lado del cliente;

```
 echo "alert('Valor cookie prueba: " + document.cookie + "');" //document.cookie, contiene todas las cookies del sitio, excepto aquellas generadas en php solo accesibles al sitio
```

2.- Codigo del lado del servidor;

```
$prueba = "prueba";
setcookie("prueba", $prueba, time()+(60*60*24*365), '/');
echo "alert('Valor cookie prueba: ". $prueba ."');"
```

Espero que sea comprensible y de utilidad.